# How to apply ng-focus and ng-change on same input field?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

Trying to call a function A when user focuses on `input` field using `ng-focus` event, and to call function B when the user starts writing and want to capture this event using `ng-change` event.

```
<input type="text" ng-focus="functionA()" ng-change="functionB()">
```

Comment: What is the problem here? What do you actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem with this? Seems to be working fine for me. The only thing I see a problem is that you haven't added `ng-model`. It is required for the `ng-change` to work.

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope) {

  $scope.functionA = function() {
    console.log("Input is focused");
  };

  $scope.functionB = function() {
    console.log("changing");
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController">
  <input type="text" ng-focus="functionA()" ng-change="functionB()" ng-model="myValue" />
</div>
```